# How to find the rotational angle of triangle $DEF$ which is as close as possible to relative angle of triangle $ABC$?

Tags: optimization, triangles, rotations, orientation, maxima-minima

I would center two triangles to the origo and find out three different positions of triangle $ΔDEF$, and select the one of those, that differs as little as possible from the orientation of triangle $ΔABC$.

### 1.

$ΔABC$ has a $Centroid_a = (A+B+C) / 3$

$ΔDEF$ has a $Centroid_b = (D+E+F) / 3$

From $Centroid_a$ we get vectors to $vA$, $vB$ and $vC$.

From $Centroid_b$ we get vectors to $vD$, $vE$ and $vF$.

### 2.

Then we translate both triangles to origo (without losing shape or size).

### 3a.

Next we rotate triangle $ΔDEF$ so that vectors $vA$ and $vD$ match each others. Calculate absolute difference of rotation of $∠vB - ∠vE + ∠vC - ∠vF$.

### 3bc.

Repeat by matching $vA$ and $vE$, and finally by matching $vA$ and $vF$.

### 4.

Finally find out the smallest rotation and rotate triangle $ΔDEF$ accordingly.

Is this the way to find out the minimal orientation difference between two triangles and/or what is the optimal algorithm to find it out?

**Addition**

Reflection / flipping discussion could be part of the optimization. Picture below shows the case, when rotation in Procrustes analysis is often unrecognizing reflections of the plane objects.

[image]

Further testing the case according to excellent answer given by @JeanMarie can be done in: https://www.geogebra.org/m/h2V7xZ9j

Comment: This is a case of the general problem of "registration"/ "matching" (useful keywords!). A rather robust tool for solving this issue is by using Procrustes' algorithm (which is linked to SVD: Singular Value decomposition) but in the case of 2D registration, there is a complex numbers version that is very simple. If I have time enough, I will give an answer using this version.

Comment: Id like to see it as 2D version avoiding SVC and I'd appreciate a lot if you get time for an answer. I used Procruster method but reflection became a problem so I wanted really to split problem down to pieces and grass level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us denote by $z_1,z_2,z_3$ (resp. $z'_1,z'_2,z'_3$) the complex numbers associated with the first (resp. second) triangle $T$ (resp. $T'$).

We look for the angle $\theta$ that has to be applied to the first triangle in order that its rotated image $R_{\theta}T$, i.e., $e^{i\theta}z_1,e^{i\theta}z_2,e^{i\theta}z_3$, is the closest possible to triangle $T'$.

The most classical minimization criterion is in the sense of least squares, i.e., we look for an angle $\theta$ such as the sum of the squares or the resp. distances:

$$|e^{i\theta}z_1-z'_1|^2+|e^{i\theta}z_2-z'_2|^2+|e^{i\theta}z_3-z'_3|^2$$

is minimal. In short the objective is to:

$$\tag{1} \text{Minimize} \ \ \ \sum_{k=1}^3|e^{i\theta}z_k-z'_k|^2$$

(for $\theta$). Using formula $|Z-Z'|^2=|Z|^2+|Z'|^2-2 \Re(\bar{Z}Z'),$ (1) becomes:

$$\text{Minimize} \ \ \ \sum_{k=1}^3|e^{i\theta}z_k|^2 + \sum_{k=1}^3|z'_k|^2 - 2 \sum_{k=1}^3 \Re (e^{-i \theta} \bar{z_k}z'_k)$$

But $|e^{-i\theta}z_k|=|z_k|$. Thus, the issue becomes:

$$\tag{2} \text{Minimize} \ \ \ \sum_{k=1}^3|z_k|^2 + \sum_{k=1}^3|z'_k|^2 - 2 \sum_{k=1}^3 \Re (e^{-i \theta} \bar{z_k}z'_k)$$

The first two sums are constant, reducing the problem to find $\theta$ such as

$$\sum_{k=1}^3 \Re (e^{-i \theta} \bar{z_k}z'_k)=\Re \left(e^{-i \theta} \sum_{k=1}^3 \bar{z_k}z'_k\right)=\Re \left(e^{-i \theta} Z \right) \ \ \text{with} \ \  Z:=\sum_{k=1}^3 \bar{z_k}z'_k$$

is **maximized** (due to the minus sign of coefficient $-2$ in (2)).

Consider the polar representation $Z=re^{i \alpha}$.

Maximization of $\Re \left(re^{-i\theta} Z \right)=\Re r\left(e^{i(\alpha-\theta)}\right)$ becomes extremely simple: take $\theta=\alpha$.

> Summarizing, Procrustes' algorithm in this context is as follows:
>
> - convert the triangles' vertices into complex numbers $z_k$ and $z'_k \ (k=1,2,3)$,
> - compute the "hermitian dot product" $Z:=\sum_{k=1}^3 \bar{z_k}z'_k$,
> - convert $Z$ into polar coordinates $Z=re^{i \alpha}$,
> - the anwer is $\theta_{optimal}=\alpha$.

Edit: an example:

If the first (resp. 2nd) triangle has coordinates

$$A_1(-2,2), \ A_2=(-3,-2), \ A_3=(5,0) \ \ \text{and} \ \ A'_1(-3,0), \ A'_2=(1,-3), \ A'_3=(4,3).$$

(note that the centroid of each triangle is 0, a necessary condition for the method to be applied ; if this has not be done, you need to translate the two triangles in such a way that the new centroids are such).

$$z_1=-2+2i, \ z_2=-3-2i, \ z_3=5 \ \ \text{and} \ \ z'_1=-3, \ z'_2=1-3i, \ z'_3=4+3i$$

$$Z=\sum_{k=1}^3 \bar{z_k}z'_k=29+32i\approx43.19e^{0.8345i}$$

The rotation angle is thus $\approx  0.8345$ radians, i.e., $\approx 47.8$ (decimal) degrees.

Comment: Of course, a preliminary translation step to place the two centroids in coincidence with the origin is essential. It can also a certain cases be necessary to scale on of the triangles.

Comment: I lost my track with three different kind of z's. Can you explain them by relating to my original ABC and DEF triangles? Especially ~z requires some interlude. Finally can you set an equation for theta = x. I think I need to boil this down to coordinate point level at the end...

Comment: For example if A=(2,2),B=(3,-6),C=(5,4) \rightarrow z_1=2+2i,z_2=3-6i,z_3=5+4i$.I will add an example to my text

Comment: An example has been added.

Comment: Brilliant! I had to find out that $\bar{z_1} = (real(z_1)-imag(z_1))$, flip the sign so to say, and that $θ = -(\frac{180 * tan^{-1}(\frac{32}{29})}{\pi})$. This might be not be in the scope of the question, but this algorithm doesn't seem to recognize reflections? It is dependant on the order of the original two triangle points. I added image to the question to visualize the case. You can find GeoGebra document to play around with it too: https://www.geogebra.org/m/h2V7xZ9j

Comment: I didn't know you had to guess that $\bar{z_1} = (real(z_1)-imag(z_1)i$ (called the conjugate complex number), otherwise, I would have recalled the definition ! In the formula for $\theta$, you have added a minus sign because you have exchanged the "moving" triangle and the fixed one. Yes, as presented, you have to know the "pairing" of vertices ; BUT, if you have not this knowledge, you can  apply the method to the $3!=6$ possible pairings, and keep the one that gives the minimum (ctd...)

Comment: (...ctd) value for the sum of the squares of distances with the 6 different $\theta$ obtained in this way, and this answers your last question : among the 6 pairings, 3 of them are associated with symmetries... (the other 3 with rotations).

Comment: As you, I use Geogebra for graphical representations: it's very handy with scores of possibilities, very complementary to Matlab for me.